# How to add text to Powershell output?

Tags: powershell, output

I am trying to add text before the output of the results from Powershell.
What I have is:

```
"This is the desktop size" | out-file -filepath "{0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem C:\users\******\desktop -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1GB) >> "c:\Program Files\*****_Inc\pc_info\folders.txt"
```

The output I would like is:
This is the desktop Size (Size of folder)

I have tried looking up like scripts, google and asked other powershell users with no luck.

Comment: You mean like `"This is the desktop size: {0:N2} GB" -f (<sizeCalculation>) >> C:\path\to\folders.txt`?

Comment: This works: "{0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem C:\users\ -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1GB) I would like it to say "The folder is (Size)" >> "c:\Program Files\*****_Inc\pc_info\folders.txt"

Comment: Yup, so change `"{0:N2} GB"` to `"This is the desktop size: {0:N2} GB"`

Comment: That worked. I will mark the question answered as soon as I figure out how.